# Different rights without identification

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet. I want to share it with people that don't necessarily have a Google account by just sending a URL.

It's ok if everyone has the same rights but what if I want some people with read-only and others with read and write rights?

Is it possible for instance to have two URLs: one for read-only and another for read and write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you "cant" have two URLs of the same document or sheet.

the closest you can get is to set **Link sharing** to **On - Anyone with the link Can view** and then invite individual people and give them individual read+write rights

[image]

the other way around is to have two URL links of two spreadsheets where one has open read+write rights for everyone with link (the original sheet) and the other one has only-read rights for everyone with link (dummy sheet that uses `IMPORTRANGE()` to import all data from the original sheet)

- Sample Usage:

`IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "Sheet1!A1:AA1000")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solution two (read only sheet with IMPORTRANGE) is perfect for my needs.